# do-release-upgrade from 18.04 to 20.04 fails because python3 is corrupted

Tags: 18.04, upgrade, python, 20.04, do-release-upgrade

I have tried upgrading from 18.04 to 20.04.1 on my laptop: however I get the `Can not upgrade - Your python3 install is corrupted. Please fix the '/usr/bin/python3' symlink."` error. I tried the workaround described in
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubuntu-release-upgrader/+bug/1825655 to no avail. The output of `ls -l /usr/bin/python*` is:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      18 ago  9 11:57 /usr/bin/python -> /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       9 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2 -> python2.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 3665768 lug 20 17:37 /usr/bin/python2.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 lug 20 17:37 /usr/bin/python2.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python2-config -> python2.7-config
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      25 ago  3 16:03 /usr/bin/python3 -> /etc/alternatives/python3
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 lug 17 14:50 /usr/bin/python3.6
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4526456 lug 17 14:50 /usr/bin/python3.6m
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5308240 giu 29 07:44 /usr/bin/python3.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      33 giu 29 07:44 /usr/bin/python3.7-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7-config
-rwxr-xr-x 2 root root 5308240 giu 29 07:44 /usr/bin/python3.7m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      34 giu 29 07:44 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config -> x86_64-linux-gnu-python3.7m-config
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     398 nov 15  2017 /usr/bin/python3-jsonschema
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      10 ott 25  2018 /usr/bin/python3m -> python3.6m
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      16 apr 16  2018 /usr/bin/python-config -> python2.7-config
```

Is it perhaps best that I reinstall Ubuntu altogether with the obvious consequences in terms of time wasted to get back operational?

Comment: You haven't said if this is a desktop or server, but an *upgrade* via re-install for Ubuntu desktop is actually significantly faster than a *release-upgrade* if you use *something-else*, existing partitions and don't format. It'll won't touch your user files (unless you format), and will auto-add back additional packages you had installed if they exist in the new release in Ubuntu repositories, then ask to reboot.

Comment: It's desktop. I see your point. I wonder if it would fix the python3-python mess for good.